# Discrete valuations on algebraic function fields: an additional condition that I don't understand

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ an [algebraic function field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function_field) over an algebraically closed field $k$. A discrete valuation on $K$ is defined as a map $v:K^\ast\to\mathbb Z$ such that

1. $v(xy)= v(x)+v(y)$
2. $v(x+y)\ge \min\{v(x),v(y)\}$

> 3. $\;v(k^\ast)=0$

Why do we require condition 3? usually for [discrete valuation fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation) there is no such condition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algebraic function fields are related to geometric objects $X$ like algebraic varieties or Riemann surfaces. These objects are defined over $k$, meaning that the equations used to define them possess coefficients in $k$. The condition $v(k^\ast)=0$ ensures that the valuation $v$ is related to the geometry of $X$ as well and is not reflecting properties of $k$ that are not interesting/relevant from a geometric point of view.

You can see this very clearly in the case of a projective irreducible algebraic curves $X$ defined over the field $k$ and having no singularities. In this case the discrete valuations of its function field $K(X)$ satisfying property 3 are in bijection with the points of $X$.

Comment: Consider a regular curve $X$ over a field $k$. Then $\mathscr O_{X,x}$ a valuation ring for $K(X)$. Call the associated valuation $v_x$. Why $v_x(k)=0$? Is it because $k$ embedds in $\mathscr O_{X,x}$?

Comment: From an algebraic point of view: yes. From a function theoretic point of view: $v_x(f)$ is the order of $f$ at $x$. Since $f$ is defined at $x$ this order must be $\geq 0$. Since elements $f\in k$ are constant as functions on $X$, the order must be $0$ for $f\neq 0$.